# SQL Count all ocourence pr date

Tags: sql, plsql, count

I have the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT   TO_DATE(DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN INITIALS is not null THEN 1 END) AS ANSWERED,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN INITIALS is not null AND RESPONSE_TIME BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN 1 END) AS ANSWERED_WITHIN_30_SEC
FROM     KS_DRIFT.V_WEBDESK_SERVICECENTER
WHERE    DATETIME BETWEEN '2014-03-19' AND '2014-04-01'
GROUP BY DATETIME
```

Which outputs the following:

[image: Error sample]

As you can see it prints out the same day with the value 1.

What i want to achieve is one value pr day.

I have tried with they keyword `DISTINCT` but sadly without any changes...

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your "DATETIME" column a DATETIME field ?
If so you should group by your TO_DATE select :

```
SELECT   TO_DATE(DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN INITIALS is not null THEN 1 END) AS ANSWERED,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN INITIALS is not null AND RESPONSE_TIME BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN 1 END) AS ANSWERED_WITHIN_30_SEC
FROM     KS_DRIFT.V_WEBDESK_SERVICECENTER
WHERE    DATETIME BETWEEN '2014-03-19' AND '2014-04-01'
GROUP BY TO_DATE(DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Explanation : DATETIME are probably all different, you need to group by DATE to have a correct count by day